# Encrypt text file using RSA public key

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, public-key-encryption, public-key

I have been given a **Public Key (key.pub file)** and with the use of the same, I want to encrypt XML file using my **C#** application.

The file is having structure as below:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
> yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuaaaaaaauuu
> pppppppppppppppaao==
>
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385229/best-practices-for-symmetric-encryption-in-net

Comment: In my opinion this question is too broad, but you might find many examples here on SO by searching with the [C# and RSA tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%2brsa?tab=Newest). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public  string Encryption(string strText)
{ 
  var publicKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX The Key Value XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var testData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

  // client encrypting data with a public key issued by server                    
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey.ToString());

   var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(testData, true);

   var base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

    string retval = base64Encrypted.ToString();

    if (HaxVal1.Equals(HaxVal))
    {
        return retval;
    }
    else
    {
        return "InvalidSignature";
    }
}
```